# Hibernate bug or incorrect mapping (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate- ERROR)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When I run the below program, I get the following exception:

> ERROR: HCANN000002: An assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a
>   bug in Hibernate) org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure:
>   Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy:
>   com.online.tutorial.elementCollection.map.LanguageStatement5

I run the below [JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit):

```
public class QuestionDataSetup5 {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionDataSetup(){
        String hindiString = new String("Hindi");
        String englishString = new String("English");
        String chineseString = new String("chinese");

        LanguageStatement5 hindiStatement = new LanguageStatement5("बिल गेट्स के जन्म की तारीख क्या है");
        LanguageStatement5 englishStatement = new LanguageStatement5("What is the date of Birth of Bill Gates");
        LanguageStatement5 ChineseStatement = new LanguageStatement5("什么是比尔·盖茨出生日期");

        Map<String, LanguageStatement5> questionMap5 = prepareMap(hindiString, englishString, chineseString, hindiStatement, englishStatement, ChineseStatement);

        Question5 dateOfBirthQuestion5 = new Question5(10, questionMap5);

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("NewPersistenceUnit");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        entityManager.persist(hindiStatement);
        entityManager.persist(englishStatement);
        entityManager.persist(ChineseStatement);

        entityManager.persist(dateOfBirthQuestion5);

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    private Map<String, LanguageStatement5> prepareMap(String hindiString, String englishString, String chineseString, LanguageStatement5 hindiStatement, LanguageStatement5 englishStatement, LanguageStatement5 chineseStatement) {
        Map<String, LanguageStatement5> questionMap5 = new HashMap<String, LanguageStatement5>();
        questionMap5.put(hindiString, hindiStatement);
        questionMap5.put(englishString, englishStatement);
        questionMap5.put(chineseString, chineseStatement);
        return questionMap5;
    }
}
```

[POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) classes:

```
package com.online.tutorial.elementCollection.map;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Question5")
public class Question5 {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "question_sequencer_generator", sequenceName = "question_sequencer" , initialValue = 10, allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "question_sequencer_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;

    @Column(name = "Max_Marks")
    private int maxMarks;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "IMAGE")
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "LANGUAGE_REF_ID")
     /*    @JoinTable(name = "QUESTION_STATEMENT_MAPPING",
                        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_REF_ID"),
                        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =     "STATEMENT_REF_ID"))  */
    private Map<String, LanguageStatement5> languageNameToQuestionMap = new TreeMap<String, LanguageStatement5>();

    public Question5() {
    }

    public Question5(int maxMarks, Map<String, LanguageStatement5> languageNameToQuestionMap) {
        this.maxMarks = maxMarks;
        this.languageNameToQuestionMap = languageNameToQuestionMap;
    }

    public Long getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(Long questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public int getMaxMarks() {
        return maxMarks;
    }

    public void setMaxMarks(int maxMarks) {
        this.maxMarks = maxMarks;
    }

    public Map<String, LanguageStatement5> getLanguageNameToQuestionMap() {
        return languageNameToQuestionMap;
    }

    public void setLanguageNameToQuestionMap(Map<String, LanguageStatement5> languageNameToQuestionMap) {
        this.languageNameToQuestionMap = languageNameToQuestionMap;
    }
}
```

Another POJO class:

```
package com.online.tutorial.elementCollection.map;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Embeddable
public class LanguageStatement5 {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "statement_sequencer_generator", sequenceName = "statement_sequencer" , initialValue = 10, allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "statement_sequencer_generator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "statement_id")
    private Long statementId;


    @Column(name = "statement")
    private String statement;

    public LanguageStatement5() {
    }

    public LanguageStatement5(String statement) {
        this.statement = statement;
    }

    public String getStatement() {
        return statement;
    }

    public void setStatement(String statement) {
        this.statement = statement;
    }
}
```

Pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LanguageStatement5` is an entity type - as suggested by `@Id` and the fact that you are trying to persist its instances directly with the entity manager - it should be declared as such: You should annotate it with `@Entity` and not with `@Embeddable`. The later is used to persist classes which are "owned" by other entities and don't have their own lifecycle and identity (`@Id`). This also means you will have to the change the mapping of `languageNameToQuestionMap` property of `Question5` from `@ElementCollection` to `@OneToMany`.

Alternatively, if `LanguageStatement5` is indeed conceptually an embedded entity, you shouldn't try to persist those there instances. Just call `entityManager.persist(dateOfBirthQuestion5);` and JPA will take care for persisting the language statement objects. This should be the only call to `persist` in your code. You should also remove `@SequenceGenerator` and `@Id` from `LanguageStatement5` in that case.